# Why is open_file in flutter not opening any files in my app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm working on a mobile app--I'm using flutter and it needs to view documents in my assets. I used the pdfviewer and it works perfectly fine. But with openfile, it does not.

I used the flutter package,
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pdf_viewer and it opens the pdf file but with this package, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/open_file it won't open any files. 
This is how i call them:

```
onPressed: () => FlutterPdfViewer.loadAsset("assets/files/sample.pdf"),

onPressed: () => OpenFile.open('assets/files/samplefile.docx'),
```

I don't know any more methods to open files in flutter. Am I using the open_file the wrong way? I hope you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Future<File> pdfAsset() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/set_any_name.pdf');
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load('assets/en/legal_notes.pdf');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
    return tempFile;
  }
pdfAsset().then((file){OpenFile.open(file.path);});
```

Hi first copy the asset to temp file then open the file with OpenFile. 
It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `pubspec.yaml` with full path of the asset.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/files/samplefile.docx
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I did what you said but it did not work. At first my pubspec.yaml is like this: `flutter: assets: -assets/files/` and I can still load the pdf within the app.

Comment: file_open only works with the files in the phone’s storage, not in my project’s assets. Is there a way to load/view files(eg. docx, pdf, excel files) from my assets like how the flutterpdfviewer does?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<File> pdfAsset() async {
    Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    File tempFile = File('${tempDir.path}/Mybook.pdf');
    ByteData bd = await rootBundle.load('assets/Mybook.pdf');
    await tempFile.writeAsBytes(bd.buffer.asUint8List(), flush: true);
    return tempFile;
  }//above code converts our asset to temp file

  Future openFile() async {
    pdfAsset().then((file) {
      OpenFile.open(file.path);
    });
  }
```

call openFile() at desired place, also I had to define my pdf in asset section of pubspec.yaml. It was not working with just assets/

```
assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/Mybook.pdf
```